# Is it ok to make calls to data layer/repo from POCO?

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture, poco

I am trying to figure out how to setup a clean architecture for my shopping cart without over architecting it or ending up with a anemic domain model.  Right now I just want to use standard ADO database logic without any ORM framework.  (I am also learning EF4.1, but not good enough yet to use in production)

Ideally I would just have a POCO for each Business object/entity and a repository/data class that will handle persistence.  To keep things simple, I am thinking to tightly couple the POCOs to the data layer and it will return POCOs.  If I add DTO to the mix as well, then I end up having 5-6 class files for each area (gc, order, items, payments, etc) which just seems like too much for a simple app.  I can always refine later.

The first class I am working on is for gift certificates.  One of the methods is to create a new GC.  In this method I will need to query the database to ensure the new code does not already exist in the system.  Is it ok to just call the data layer/repo inside this method?

Should the data layer/repo be static?  Should I only expose it through the POCO itself?

Should I drop the data layer altogether and just have  the data calls directly in my POCOs (active record style)?

I need a simple architecture which will allow me some separation of concerns without over complicating things.  The database provider and table structures will not change for at least the next few years.

Here is some code.. just need to figure out where the parts go.

```
public GiftCertificateModel
{
    public int GiftCerticiateId {get;set;}
    public string Code {get;set;}
    public decimal Amount {get;set;}
    public DateTime ExpirationDate {get;set;}

    public void Redeem(string code, decimal amount)
    {
        //need to validate the input
        //need to insert a record to the transaction log table (call the repo or does this entire method need to be in the repo?)
    }

    public void GetNewCode()
    {
        //need to create random alpha num code
        //need to make sure the code is unique in the db... (again, (call the repo or does this entire method need to be in the repo?
    }

}




public GiftCertificateRepo : DALBase (DALBase has methods for connecting, etc)
{

    //mapping code here to map SQLDataReader values to GiftCertificateModel properties
    //i can also setup separate DTOs if it makes more sense...

    //should the repo be static?
    public static GiftCertificateModel GetById(int GiftCertificateId)
    {
        //call db to get one and return single model

    }

    public static bool IsUnique(string code)
    {
        //call db to see if any records exists for code

    }

    public static List<GiftCertificateModel> GetMany()
    {
        //call db to get many and return list

    }

    public static void Save(GiftCertificateModel gc)
    {
        //call db to save

    }
}
```

Calling code:

```
GiftCertificateModel gc = new GiftCertificateModel();
gc.Code = gc.GetNewCode(); //do i call the is unique here or in the GetNewCode method?
gc.Amount = 10;
gc.ExpirationDate = "1/1/2012";
GiftCertificateRepo.Save(gc);
```

Comment: Please don't give your GC a Collect() method.

Comment: Can't your create your NewCode at the DB level? In my application, I usually create a new guid in the Stored Proc before saving a new record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By keeping the POCOs (representations of data) separate from the repository objects (representations of how data gets stored/retrieved) you will be able to much more easily switch from ADO to a more advanced ORM system in the future - those code changes will be isolated to one place.

Better yet, define an IRepository interface and have your ADO repostiory class implement it.  Then, your app should work only with IRepository thus making it even easier to test or switch repository implementations in the future.

Comment: @Robert Levy - I am just not understanding exactly how to apply the repository pattern to my solution.

Comment: @developr - I would replace this: "GiftCertificateModel gc = new GiftCertificateModel();gc.Code = gc.GetNewCode();" with "GiftCertificateModel gc = gcRepo.CreateNew();" and then the repo is reponsible for creating the gc object and giving it a valid code

Comment: @Robert Levy - thanks for your advice.  So I would just pass the parameters (exp date, amount, etc) to the repo method?  Would input validation then be done in the repo as well?  If so, then what types of "rich" functionality would ever go in the poco?

Comment: @developr - validation can go in the model.  i wouldn't pass those parameters to the CreateNew method, you can set those properties after getting back the object.  but let CreateNew do work that is repository-specific (ensuring good, unique codes for new GCs)

Comment: @Robert Levy - Just to clarify, is it ok to create a gc object outside the repository?  And, as I understand it, the repo should never be called in the POCO itself for any reason?

Comment: @developr, no create/retrieving/updating/deleting your GC objects are all responsibilities of the GC repository

Comment: @Robert Levy - Just not sure why I couldn't create the GC outside the repo, then use the repo to save it.  Sorry, trying to get my head around it all. Or do I just have a generic method in my repo to return a empty GC object for this purpose?

Comment: @developr - you want the repo to do the object creation for scenarios just like yours... there are initialization steps that only the repo knows how to accomplish (like coming up with unique ids)

Comment: @Robert Levy - Awesome...thanks for continuing to help out.  I think I am getting somewhere.  Right now I am just creating a new gc in the repo using a CreateNew and then returning it.  One thing I am stuck on now is how to update the POCO db ID once I do the save in the repo.  Please check out this question and let me know if I am getting it right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102717/how-should-the-repository-pattern-update-the-id-of-the-object-after-a-save-to-dat

Answer (score 5):

By definition a POCO is persistance ignorant, i.e. it doesn't know that and how it is being persisted.

If you couple your business objects to your repositories or persistance layer, that might be perfectly fine depending on your circumstances, but it wouldn't be POCOs anymore.

Comment: As long as the POCOs are unaware of the persistance layer, then what difference would it make if the persistance layer itself can accept/return POCOs?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. I thought you wanted to include the persistance calls in you POCOs, wghich then wouldn't be POCOs anymore.

Comment: how should I handle situations in my POCOs where I need to get data to compute a property or check for existence?  Should those be separate service classes (eg - need to see if the GC code is unique, if not it should give a new code).  Seems silly to have this logic in the codebehind file.

Comment: I would either use a service class to orchestrate or use dependency injection to hand over a repository to the business object.

Comment: DI is a bit over my head at this point. BTW, do you recommend moving toward EF or ... ?

Answer (score 2):

There are several systems/ideologies out there, but they all agree that Persistence is not part of the business class. Make a separate Data Access Layer for storing & retrieving your POCOs.

Comment: From what I have read, you should have a rich domain model, so I assume it is OK to have validation and other business logic in the POCO itself (otherwise it is just a DTO / anemic model).  So, when a new GC is created, the code needs to be checked against the db to see if it is unique... How do I handle that?

Comment: @developr - see my comment below