# How should the repository pattern update the ID of the object after a save to database method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repository-pattern

After I create my POCO in memory, I call the Save method on the repository object.  I need to then update the POCO with the database ID created during the save operation.  Should I pass the object in using ref, simply have the save method return the ID and manually update the object from the calling page, or what?

Here is some sample code:

```
public GiftCertificateModel
{
    public int GiftCerticiateId {get;set;}
    public string Code {get;set;}
    public decimal Amount {get;set;}
    public DateTime ExpirationDate {get;set;}

    public bool IsValid()
    {}
}




public GiftCertificateRepository
{

    public GiftCertificateModel GetById(int GiftCertificateId)
    {
        //call db to get one and return single model
    }

    public List<GiftCertificateModel> GetMany()
    {
        //call db to get many and return list
    }

    public string GetNewUniqueCode()
    {
        //randomly generates unique code
        return code;
    }

    public GiftCertificateModel CreateNew()
    {
        GiftCertificateModel gc = new GiftCertificateModel();
        gc.Code = GetNewUniqueCode();
        return gc;
    }


    //should this take by ref or just return the id or return a full new model?
    public void Save(GiftCertificateModel gc)
    {
        //call db to save
    }
}

GiftCertificateRepository gcRepo = new GiftCertificateRepository();
GiftCertificateModel gc = gcRepo.CreateNew();
gc.Amount = 10.00M;
gc.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(12);
gc.Notes = "Test GC";
gcRepo.Save(gc);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repository should save your POCO so simply fill `gc.Id` in the `Save` method by querying the `Id` after persisting the object and calling method will see that.

```
GiftCertificateRepository gcRepo = new GiftCertificateRepository();
GiftCertificateModel gc = gcRepo.CreateNew();
gc.Amount = 10.00M;
gc.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(12);
gc.Notes = "Test GC";
gcRepo.Save(gc);
int Id = gc.Id; // Save populate the Id
```

Comment: This is what I do. It makes it 'feel funny' to have a settable-ID on the POCO but it seems to work best. Probably need to do the same for other fields like CreateDate, etc.

Comment: Accessibility of ID depends on the layer (assembly) where POCO is defined. If it is defined in the same layer as repository you can make ID setter internal but you most probably don't want to do that because it will break some scenarios for data binding in ASP.NET. Yes you can do the same for other automatically filled properties.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka - Thanks for the response, but how are you actually getting the ID back from the repo?  Should the original gc created be a instance that is set in the repo? (please see my sample code in the original post)  Glad to see I am at least on the right track!

Comment: Is `GiftCertificateModel` a class? In such case parameter passed to the `Save` method is a reference and every change made to its content will be visible in calling method as well.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka - Yes, it is a class, but the Save method is in the separate class GiftCertificateRepository which handles all persistance.  As I understand it, POCO should not have any Get/Save methods.

Comment: It doesn't matter. If you pass `gc` instance as parameter to method anywhere any changes made to `gc` content are visible outside of that method because the method gets only reference to shared instance.

Comment: I tend to implement ID's backing field as an int?, and expose it using a property that will throw InvalidOperationException if you try to set the ID a second time (i.e., when the field is not null).  It still feels odd to have ID be settable, but at least I'll hear about it if I accidentally abuse that characteristic.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka - OMG! You are 100% correct.  I thought you had to explicitly pass as a ref parameter for it to work that way.  I have been doing it quite wrong for some time now.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka - In general, do you think my architecture is ok to move forward?  I am still learning EF4, but still have a while to go before I can use it in production.  My previous efforts at n-layer ended up as anemic domain, so now I am trying to use better architecture with rich domain objects and persistance ignorant POCOs

Comment: Passing `ref` parameter allows you changing the instance `gc` references - it means replacing the whole object and reflect this change in the calling code.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka - Thanks again!  Now I need to figure out what kinds of things I should have in a separate Business layer and/or service layer.  Figuring out what goes where is a real challenge.